# Is it okay to skip heading levels when creating html pages?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an html page with heading and subheadings, I'm using Bootstrap v4 CSS.
I was using `h3` for heading and `h4` for subheading, but when rendered I found the sizes too similar so I swapped to using `h2` and `h4`, not using h3 at all.

This works fine, but is it okay to do this semantically or is it incorrect?

Because I am using Bootstrap I dont particularly want to override the CSS  for `h3` to make it larger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want *semantically correct* HTML, then it would be okay to keep the hierarchy; you should **NOT** use different heading tags *just* for styling purposes; if you are choosing an `h4` over an `h3` solely because of the sizes, then that would be semantically wrong; I'd just stick to change the sizes with my own CSS.

This article is really great to help with this:  [Why Use Semantic HTML](https://www.lifewire.com/why-use-semantic-html-3468271)

And quoting the same article:

> h1–h6 - The heading tags can be used to make fonts bigger and bolder,
>   but if the text is not a heading, it should not be inside a heading
>   tag. Use the font-weight and font-size CSS properties instead if you
>   want to change the size or weight of specific text on your page

Also, since you are using **Bootstrap**, they provide classes that apply the styles of each heading to an element; so you can choose to style an `h3` heading like a `h1`; this way you keep the looks you need while also the correct semantic approach:[Headings](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/typography/#headings)

Comment: ah, thanks okay that is what I shod do apply h2 class to h3

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use `h3` at all, on your page then yes, it should be all good semantically.

However, if you will be using an `h3` somewhere else, I would just alter the heading sizes using CSS as there is not much of another choice, that would be considered semantically incorrect to skip a heading level then use it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Skipping heading levels is a poor practice from the perspective of information design, whether we are talking about web pages, books, journal articles, or about anything else. You can not only confuse screen readers but all readers when you don't follow a consistent, logical pattern with your heading structure.